# mysql query convert to mysqli

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, mysqli

I am using the below query with the server setting as mysql in Joomla quite successfully, but can't get it run using the settings as mysqli in joomla Fabrik extension.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT first_name,mobile FROM students WHERE
DAY(dob) = DAY(CURDATE()) AND
MONTH(dob) = MONTH(CURDATE())");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
//mycode- to - send SMS
    }
```

I have modified the above code for mysqli as below with no success:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT first_name,mobile FROM students WHERE
DAY(dob) = DAY(CURDATE()) AND
MONTH(dob) = MONTH(CURDATE())");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
//mycode- to - send SMS
    }
```

What other changes I need to make in the above query so that I can use it using mysqli settings.

Thanks.

Comment: What $query variable is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla has it own database class so you don't need to use the likes of `mysqli_*`. Use something along the lines of the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('first_name', 'mobile')));
->from($db->quoteName('#__students'))
->where($db->quoteName('DAY(dob) = DAY(CURDATE())' AND 'MONTH(dob) = MONTH(CURDATE())'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    your code here
}
```

For more information in Joomla database queries, read this:

http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion, but how come the first part of myquery works just fine using server settings as mysql in Joomla.

Comment: Have you changed the database type in the global configuration in the Joomla backend to use **mysqli** ? Either way, you should not be using this code. **mysql_*** is deprecated and Joomla has it's own class for database queries which caters for things like this

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the query partly according to the suggestion by **Lodder**. My final query looks like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',1)first_name,mobile FROM students WHERE
DAY(dob) = DAY(CURDATE()) AND
MONTH(dob) = MONTH(CURDATE())";

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();


foreach ($results as $result) {
$mobile = $result->mobile;
$name = $result->first_name; 

//further code
}
```